# nearprotocol question about reactJS <h1>test

Tags: reactjs, nearprotocol

nearprotocol test

I'm new to React and NEAR and trying to understand how my frontend React app can call methods on the contract.

In the near cli i can call near view $NFT_CONTRACT_ID nft_total_supply which returns the amount of NFTs on the contract.

nearprotocol test

In the near cli i can call near view $NFT_CONTRACT_ID nft_total_supply which returns the amount of NFTs on the test